# C++ Visual Studio 2015: non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

Card.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include "Rank.h"
#include "Suit.h"
using namespace std;

/**
 * 
 */
class MEMORYWARS_API Card
{
public:
    Card(Rank, Suit);
    string toString() const;
    ~Card();
private:
    Rank rank;
    Suit suit;
};
```

Card.cpp

```
#include "MemoryWars.h"
#include "Card.h"

Card::Card(Rank rank, Suit suit)
{
    this->rank = rank;
    this->suit = suit;
}

string Card::toString() const
{
    string s = "Hellow there";
    return s;
}

Card::~Card()
{
}
```

Error

```
error C3867: 'Card::toString': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
```

Deck.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Card.h"
#include "vector"
class MEMORYWARS_API Deck
{
public:
    Deck();
    ~Deck();
private:
    std::vector<Card> deck;
};
```

Deck.cpp

```
#include "MemoryWars.h"
#include "Deck.h"
#include <EngineGlobals.h>
#include <Runtime/Engine/Classes/Engine/Engine.h>
Deck::Deck()
    : deck(52)
{
    int cc = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++)
        {
            Rank rank = static_cast<Rank>(j);
            Suit suit = static_cast<Suit>(i);
            deck[cc] = Card(rank, suit);
            cc++;
        }
    }
    string st = deck[2].toString;
    GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 5.f, FColor::Red, FString::Printf(TEXT("Some variable values: x: %s"), st));
}

Deck::~Deck()
{
}
```

I'm new to C++ with Java experience mainly, I have been struggling with this error.

I'm trying to test the Card::toString method but everytime I call it from deck.cpp I get an error.

Comment: `string st = deck[2].toString();`  If you want to call the function, you need parens.

Comment: Calling member function is basically done the same in C++ as in Java.

Comment: My apology this is such a stupid mistake...facepalm Anyway, I updated my post. I started getting another error, would you please help me.

Comment: `Deck(52)` tries to construct 52 cards by `Card()`, but there is no such default (read: no parameters) constructor. Define a default constructor or store `Card`s as pointers. (In Java, they would presumably be initially null, because Java does everything by reference. In C++, object or reference is a distinction you must make explicitly.)

Comment: @alcedine probably just wants to `deck.reserve(52)` and `deck.push_back(Card(rank, suit))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line here is not correct:

```
string st = deck[2].toString;
```

The proper way to call a function in C++ (actually Java too I thought) is this:

```
string st = deck[2].toString();
```

Comment: My apology this is such a stupid mistake...facepalm
Anyway, I updated my post. I started getting another error, would you please help me.

Comment: @Lopic that belongs to another question. Please, do not correct the error in your​ question because the answer the there to correct it.

Comment: @Lopic: I've rolled back the question to the original state. If you can't fix your new problem, even after reducing it to a [mcve], then you can ask a new question.